# What is the difference between callable HTTPS functions and HTTPS functions with param?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

In HTTPS Callable function if the statement checks whether context.auth exist,
does it guarantee that the calling user is authenticated and is same as the context.auth.uid?

after reading this [code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js)  and this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#java_2) i am getting mixed thoughts on how these functions work

In the code it uses a pram to get and check if the pram has the auth token.
In the second doc it uses just the context to get the auth token.

i am thinking the first code is old then the code in doc, can someone clear this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example is **not** a Callable Cloud Function, but rather a regular HTTP(S) Cloud Function/web hook. In the implementation of that example, it decodes the `req.headers.authorization` header and verifies its correctness with `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)`. The client that calls this Cloud Function will need to ensure it passes a valid ID token in the `authorization` header.

The second example **is** a Callable Cloud Function. Here the Functions SDK on the client automatically passes the ID token, and the Functions SDK on the server automatically decodes and verified that token. So it's pretty much the same process that happened before, you just don't have to write the code for it yourself.

Comment: okay, thanks got it